# Simplify $\tan(\arcsin(x))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My calculus book proves that:
$$\tan(\arcsin(x))=\tan\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\quad\text{for}\quad0\le x<1$$

I fully understand the proof (involving the drawing of a rectangular with angle $\theta$), until the last step which says: "Because both sides of the above equation are odd functions of $x$, the same result holds for $-1<x<0$"

QUESTION: I don't understand this very last step. Could you shed any light on that?

Comment: The book, I think, is saying that for both $\tan \theta$ and $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$, $f(x)=-f(-x)$, thus if it is true for $0\le x <1$, then it is true for $-x$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very last step can be translated to

$$0\le-x<1\implies \tan(\arcsin(x))=-\tan(-\arcsin(x))=-\tan(\arcsin(-x))=-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$$

equivalent to

$$-1<x\le0\implies \tan(\arcsin(x))=\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Oddness of the functions allows the minus sign to "cross" them.

Comment: Fixed a flaw in the logics. Note that $-x$ is positive so that the equivalence can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is odd if $f(x)=-f(-x)$.

So, let $f(x) = \tan(\arcsin(x))$ and $g(x) = x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

We know that $f(x) = g(x)$ when $x \in [0,1]$. Now suppose $x \in [-1,0]$. Then $-x \in [0,1]$, and so $f(-x)=g(-x)$. But then
\begin{align}
f(x) &= -f(-x) \quad \text{since $f$ is odd}  \\
     &= -g(-x) \quad \text{since $-x \in [0,1]$}  \\
     & = g(x) \quad \text{since $g$ is odd}  \\
\end{align}

Comment: I think function $f$ is odd iff $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Comment: @kamil09875.  Oops. Fixed. Thanks.